# Why does not progressBar change in dispatch_group_async?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'd like to show progressbar when someting, but progress bar does not changed. 
What I supposed to do?

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
dispatch_queue_t queue= dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0);

dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        dispatch_group_async(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
            self.progressBar.progress = (float)i/100;
        });

        // do big somethings
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your original question, you were setting `progress` as an integer between 0 and 100. If this is a `UIProgressView`, then `progress` is a floating point and should go from 0 to 1.0.

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
dispatch_queue_t queue= dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0);

dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        dispatch_group_async(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
            self.progressBar.progress = ((CGFloat) i) / 100.0;
        });

        // do big somethings
    }
});
```

Or, more simply, since you're not really using the group (you only have one operation on the global queue, and groups are generally redundant when dealing with serial queues):

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0);

dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
            self.progressBar.progress = ((CGFloat) i) / 100.0;
        });

        // do big somethings
    }
});
```

If you're still not seeing the progress view update, then it's got to be something simple like an `IBOutlet` that isn't hooked up correctly. Make sure `self.progressBar` is not `nil`. Try setting its `progress` to `0.5` and make sure that gets reflected properly.

Comment: OK, changed progress in the code, but I guess this is not critical.

Comment: @dobiho Your latest edit to the answer looks good. If you're not seeing your update, then I would suspect your `IBOutlet`. The code in my answer above updates the progress view fine. If it isn't for you, then it might be something simple like the `IBOutlet`. Check to make sure that `self.progressBar` is not `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.company.myqueue", NULL);
```

to update progress status, because

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
```

is concurrent queue.

Answer (score -1):

You should update your progress bar in the main thread :

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);

dispatch_async(queue, ^{

    // async stuff

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        // sync stuff
    });
});

dispatch_release(queue);
```

Comment: He is using the main queue for the UI update. Also, no need to dispatch UI updates synchronously. Why freeze the background queue if the foreground queue is tied up doing something else? `dispatch_async` is generally preferable.

Comment: Like @Rob pointed out, this answer is not answering the question and gives ill advice.